# A co-worker resigned and now I'm trying to find/change a piece of code he wrote

Tags: html, css, wordpress

A colleague of mine, our go-to web guy, created a DIV with an ID of "pricingswitch" - the pricing switch essentially switches the pricing table from USD, to GBP to Euro. The problem is that he set it up using the words US, UK and Europe. I managed to fix up the css to better reflect what we want it to look like but I'm not sure where I need to go to access the core files so that I can change US to USD, UK to GBP and Europe to Euro.

This is the code. I found it using the inspect feature in Chrome.

```
    <div id="pricingswitch">
      <a href="javascript:(void);" id="uspricing" class=
      "currentpricing">US</a>
      <a href="javascript:void;" id="ukpricing">UK</a>
      <a href="javascript:void;" id="eupricing">EUROPE</a>
    </div>
```

I'm hoping someone will be able to tell me where I need to go to access this code/file. I have access to the CPanel. I'm just not sure where to begin looking for this exact piece of code.

The site is built on Wordpress. If you need a link to the site or any other information from me, just ask.

Comment: Tell your boss to hire a developer... Not being condescending, but someone who knows these basic fundamentals should be manipulating this code for you, to prevent any accidental damage to the site.

Comment: Welcome, @santinodela. I don't think this is the right place to ask this question because it isn't really related to programming. See [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) This seems like more of work-related knowledge transfer issue. That said, if you have access to the files, try doing a multi-file search for those class names to see which files they are included in.

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me and for the advice. I understand now that this wasn't the right place to ask this question. I was just hoping that someone here might be able to help me out. I will try to figure it out on my own. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You have access to the code file and you do not know where this code is coming from, You can try hardcoding the following into your footer.php

You may also have the option to view these files from your wp-admin dashboard section.

You may directly change the text for these anchor tags as:

```js
<style>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#uspricing").text('USD');
    $("#ukpricing").text('GBP');
    $("#eupricing").text('Euro');
});
<style>
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you for helping me out. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Drop this in the SSH terminal and it will tell you all files that contain "pricingswitch" in the current directory, recursively....

`DIRSS=$(pwd); grep -inIEr --color=ALWAYS "pricingswitch" $DIRSS`

---

Alternatively, most IDE's have a feature that will do this. Check the documentation for the IDE you're using to find out how.